# customs sticks in piecharts using highcharts

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I am trying to create a piechart using highcharts. And I am facing one problem: The sticks that are denoting the contents are not editable, meaning I am not able to customize it, say giving a different color or make the stick size small/big or thin/thick whatever.

Here is the code.  Please help me to resolve.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5],
        color: '#000'
    }]
});
```

[image]

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/w7qf9ag5/ check https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.connectorWidth

Comment: Hi deep it was very useful , thank you and is it possible to give a custom color inside the pie chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set colors globally as

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572',
    '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'
  ],
});
```

Or you can override global colors in series

```
 series: [{
    data: [{
        name: 'Firefox',
        y: 44.2,
        color: "#fff"
      },
      ['IE7', 26.6],
      ['IE6', 20],
      ['Chrome', 3.1],
      ['Other', 5.4]
    ]
  }]
```

Change size of connector

```
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      dataLabels: {
        connectorWidth: 20
      }
    }
  },
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ptfzs4qx/)